# What does polkit authorization do to a process?

Tags: debian, polkit

I want to let my user edit a configuration file in `/etc` from my graphical C application.  One method is:

```
fprintf( fopen("/tmp/tmpfile", "w+") , "content\n"); // Write to a tmpfile
system("pkexec mv /tmp/tmpfile /etc/myapp.conf");    // Use pkexec to move that tmpfile to our file
```

However, I'd like to implement a polkit [client](https://linux.die.net/man/8/polkit) (as what I have to do is a little more complicated than a single write).This will cause the desktop's polkit agent to pop-up asking to authenticate as the administrator (root). Once authenticated, it will perform the action, then return to unprivileged use.

I've implemented [client reference API](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/ref-api.html) and added `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions` up until the point where this function (simplified version here) returns `TRUE`;

```
int IsAuthorized(const char* action) {
    PolkutAuthorizationResult* r = polkit_authority_check_authorization_sync(
        polkit_authority_get_sync(NULL, &error),
        polkit_unix_process_new_for_owner( getpid(), 0, getuid() ),
        "org.myapp.editconfig",
        NULL, /* details */
        POLKIT_CHECK_AUTHORIZATION_FLAGS_ALLOW_USER_INTERACTION,
        NULL, /* cancellable */
        &error
    );
    return polkit_authorization_result_get_is_authorized( r );
}
```

This authorizes this action:

```
<action id="org.myapp.editconfig">
  <description>Edit myapp config</description>
  <message>Authentication is required to edit this system-wide config file</message>
  <defaults>
    <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>
    <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
    <allow_active>auth_admin</allow_active>
  </defaults>
</action>
```

But my question is:  now what?  I'm not sure what "being authorized" did for me. If I try to open a `root:root` file for writing, I get permission denied.  If I create a new file, it's owned by the user, not root.

Looking into the sources of [pkexec](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/polkit/polkit/-/blob/0.105/src/programs/pkexec.c) I see it changes the uid/gid of itself.  Does authentication simply give [`CAP_SETUID` and `CAP_SETGID`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) to the process?

Assuming this is true, I tried to use [`setreuid()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setreuid) and [`setregid()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setregid):

```
int uid = getuid();    int euid = geteuid();
int gid = getgid();    int egid = getegid();

setregid(0,0);  // Switch to root
setreuid(0,0);

fprintf( fopen("/etc/myapp.conf", "w+"), "content\n");  // Write the file

setregid(gid,egid);  // Switch back
setreuid(uid,euid);
```

I find that `setreuid(0,0)` fails and I never switch users like [pkexec](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkexec) does.  Note I skipped a few things `pkexec` does such as set the environment, and `set_close_exec` for all file descriptors.

I must be missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`polkit_authority_check_authorization_sync` simply checks whether the caller is authorized to perform the action based on the polkit rules and that's it. This usually means an application/daemon that is already running as root wants to check whether the caller is actually allowed to perform certain action and then performs it on the behalf of the caller. Polkit itself doesn't grant any extra permission, your application already needs to be able to perform the action. `pkexec <command>` works because `pkexec` is a [setuid binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) so the process runs as root and only checks if you are authorized to run the command you are trying to run.

Comment: Wow.  I totally misunderstood `polkit`, but that makes sense.  I completely missed the `setuid` bit.  It looks like I'll need to put my logic into a smaller binary or script and call `pkexec` on it.  Reading `[man pkexec(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/policykit-1/pkexec.1.en.html)` I see that I can still add custom actions so I can customize the message to the user when the polkit-agent appears.

Comment: You can also simply run the entire app as root with `pkexec`, it's not recommended but if it's something small, it could be the easiest way. GParted does this -- `gparted` binary is just a small bash script that basically runs `pkexec gpartedbin` and has its own [simple polkit rule](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gparted/-/blob/master/org.gnome.gparted.policy.in.in) to allow that.